# tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 403 When using dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, tweepy, http-status-code-403

Im'm trying to run a python tweepy script using Dockefile.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN pip install tweepy

RUN pip install pymongo
RUN pip install asyncio

ADD tweepy_twitter_stream_v0.6.py /


CMD [ "python", "./tweepy_twitter_stream_v0.6.py" ]
```

tweepy_twitter_stream_v0.6.py is my python script that I'm trying to run on docker image. 
the file searches for hashtags and insert the tweet into mongoDB:

```
# Send a request to Twitter's server and save the data on tweepy iterator using hashtag_name.
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=hashtag_name,count=100,wait_on_rate_limit=True ,wait_on_rate_limit_notify= True).items():

        # Convert tweepy object into json format 
        tweet_as_json = tweet._json  
        # Insert tweet to mongoDB 
        tweets.insert_one(tweet_as_json)
```

It works perfectly fine when I run it on Jupyter notebook 
how ever, when I try to run it using dockerfile I get the following error message:

```
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=hashtag_name,count=100,wait_on_rate_limit=True ,wait_on_rate_limit_notify= True).items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 49, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 197, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 108, in next
    data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 403
```

This is how I use docker:

- build the docker file
- run the docker image
  -

both went well and I got the image name. then I ran this command in the Docker toolbox command line:

```
    docker run f384c515d331
```

f384c515d331 is the image name. I still get the same error message.

Please help this is really frustrating ;(

Answer (score -1):

[HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) indicates a forbidden status to the request.

> HTTP 403 is a standard HTTP status code communicated to clients by an HTTP server to indicate that the server understood the request, but will not fulfill it for some reason related to authorization.

It's likely that your API calls lack proper authentication, although it's hard to say without seeing your full code. Please review the [Tweepy authentication guide.](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.6.0/auth_tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I guess it's not an authentication issues cause as I mentioned it's working perfectly on jupyter notebook.

Comment: Check that your data plan includes access to the endpoint you’re trying to use. You may also need to get your App allowlisted (e.g. Engagement API) or sign up for access (e.g. Twitter Developer Labs).